# Can i run specific functions from 1 cpp file in terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, jenkins, terminal

I have 3 jobs on jenkins, 1 to build a test program, 2 are to run the test program after the build is complete. The issue I have is I need a specific 2 functions to run on one of the jobs and the other 5 functions to run on the 2nd test job, all the functions are on 1 cpp file.

Im not sure if I have to edit something in a Makefile, ive tried running `. ./test.cpp && func()` which didnt work and not sure what else to research.

Comment: I suppose the two different test jobs require that the two different sets of functions in the same source file need to be compiled as part of the build and then linked in with the rest of the build components so that the tests can be conducted? So do you need to do one build with the source file providing one set of functions and a second build with the source file using the other set of functions? Are the function names different or are you reusing the same function names for different source code bodies?

Comment: You cannot run cpp files directly, they have to be compiled first. Even when they have been compiled you cannot choose which function from within the cpp file to run. You always run the `main` function.

Comment: if you really need to do this, you can do it by structuring your main() function to call the required function, depending on the parameters passed to your executable

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly reference specific functions in an executable. At best you can alter the test program to accept parameters that can be used to specify which functions to call.

A simpler solution is to separate the tests into two files.

If you have the time and inclination, there are many test frameworks out there that you can possibly leverage.